# Determining whether an inequality provides sufficient information to determine the limit

Tags: calculus

State whether the inequality provides sufficient information to determine the $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ f(x) } $, and if so, find the limit.

$$4x-5\le f(x)\le x^{ 2 }\\ 2x-1\le f(x)\le x^{ 2 }\\ 4x-x^{ 2 }\le f(x)\le x^{ 2 }+2$$

I read about the Squeeze Theorem and watched the Khan Academy video on it but I don't understand what the question is asking here exactly. I would like an explanation which would help me arrive to the answers by myself. Direct answers do not help me.

Comment: Are these three separate problems?

Comment: @mapierce271 yes they are.

Comment: Kudos for asking for the information that will allow you to reach the answer, rather than the answer alone.  Can you state the Squeeze Theorem in your own words?

Comment: It basically saids that when the limit of say an upper function $u(x)$ and the lower function, $l(x)$ approach the same limit and a function $f(x)$ is squeezed in between them then their limits at the point in which they are all squeezed will be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the examples $2)$ and $3)$, the values for the bounding functions for $x=1$ are identical, so
 the limit is simply that value. In the first example, this is not the case, so we cannot conclude the limit here.

Answer (score 0):

A general direction for intuition:
We can use the squeeze theorem if a certain function is defined and has a limit at a punctured environment of the the other functions.
Now think about what would occur if the greater function had a limit that is different from the smaller function (generally should also verify these limits exist), as x approaches 1. What would that picture look like, and what would it suggest about f(x), if anything?